# Summing chemical properties in a CSV stream

Tags: csv, go

I have written my first program in go. It's rewritten from python.

Program takes csv file, emulates query `SELECT X, Y, SUM(Conc), SUM(ToxConc) FROM very_big_table GROUP BY X, Y`. And runs on terabytes of data.

It's written messy, but runs 100x faster than same program written in python.

Here is full [code](https://gist.github.com/tigrus/e5d9bed4cde33773284d2c7dc4468beb).

As you can see, there are a lot of repeating constructions.

What is reasonable way to rid off from constructions like?

```
if has_chemical_numbers {
    CN := record[4]
    i, _ := strconv.Atoi(CN)
    if !take_it {
        take_it = chemical_numbers[i]
    }
}
```

And.. How efficient this part in terms of memory usage?

```
//Aggregating results
for {
    record, err := r2.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }

    X, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[0])
    Y, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[1])
    Conc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(record[2], 32)
    ToxConc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(record[3], 32)

    var key Coordinates
    key.X = X
    key.Y = Y

    conc := results[key]
    conc.Conc += Conc
    conc.ToxConc += ToxConc

    results[key] = conc
}
```

Full code list:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/docopt/docopt-go"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Coordinates struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

type SConc struct {
    Conc    float64
    ToxConc float64
}

func raw_to_map(param interface{}) map[int]bool {
    numbers := make(map[int]bool)
    if param == nil {
        return numbers
    }
    _numbers := strings.Split(param.(string), ",")
    for _, i := range _numbers {
        j, err := strconv.Atoi(i)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        numbers[j] = true
    }
    fmt.Println(numbers)
    return numbers
}

func main() {

    usage := `Chemical Sum.
Usage:
    chemical
    chemical <input_file>
    chemical <input_file> <output_file> [--chemical=<ch>] [--facility=<fc>] [--media=<md>] [--restore=<file>]
    chemical --help

Options:
    --chemical=<ch>      Query by chemical number
    --facility=<fc>      Query by facility number
    --media=<md>         Query by media
    --restore=<file>     Restore from file
    --help               Show this screen
    `
    arguments, _ := docopt.Parse(usage, nil, true, "Naval Fate 2.0", false)
    input_file := arguments["<input_file>"].(string)
    output_file := arguments["<output_file>"].(string)

    raw_chemical_numbers := arguments["--chemical"]
    chemical_numbers := raw_to_map(raw_chemical_numbers)
    has_chemical_numbers := len(chemical_numbers) != 0

    raw_facility_numbers := arguments["--facility"]
    facility_numbers := raw_to_map(raw_facility_numbers)
    has_facility_numbers := len(facility_numbers) != 0

    raw_media_numbers := arguments["--media"]
    media_numbers := raw_to_map(raw_media_numbers)
    has_media_numbers := len(media_numbers) != 0

    rf, err := os.Open(input_file)
    r := csv.NewReader(rf)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error: %s", err)
    }
    csvfile, err := os.Create(output_file + ".temp")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
    defer csvfile.Close()
    writer := csv.NewWriter(csvfile)

    i := 0

    fmt.Printf("\n")

    take_it := true
    filters := has_chemical_numbers || has_media_numbers || has_facility_numbers

    //Reading and filtering csv
    for {
        record, err := r.Read()

        if i == 0 {
            i += 1
            //header = strings.Join(record, ",")
            continue
        }
        i += 1

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        //data.columns = 'gridcode,X,Y,ReleaseNumber,ChemicalNumber,FacilityNumber,Media,Conc,ToxConc,Score,ScoreCancer,ScoreNonCancer,Pop'.split(',')
        if filters {
            take_it = false
        }
        if has_chemical_numbers {
            CN := record[4]
            i, _ := strconv.Atoi(CN)
            if !take_it {
                take_it = chemical_numbers[i]
            }
        }
        if has_facility_numbers {
            FN := record[5]
            i, _ := strconv.Atoi(FN)
            if !take_it {
                take_it = facility_numbers[i]
            }
        }
        if has_media_numbers {
            M := record[6]
            i, _ := strconv.Atoi(M)
            if !take_it {
                take_it = media_numbers[i]
            }
        }
        X := record[1]
        Y := record[2]
        Conc := record[7]
        ToxConc := record[8]

        if take_it {
            new_record := []string{X, Y, Conc, ToxConc}
            writer.Write(new_record)
        }

        fmt.Printf("\rProcessed %d\r", i)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
    writer.Flush()

    fmt.Println("Preparings done.")

    fmt.Println("Aggregating data..")

    rf2, err := os.Open(output_file + ".temp")
    r2 := csv.NewReader(rf2)

    csvfile2, err := os.Create(output_file)
    writer2 := csv.NewWriter(csvfile2)

    results := make(map[Coordinates]SConc)

    //Aggregating results
    for {
        record, err := r2.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        X, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[0])
        Y, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[1])
        Conc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(record[2], 32)
        ToxConc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(record[3], 32)

        var key Coordinates
        key.X = X
        key.Y = Y

        conc := results[key]
        conc.Conc += Conc
        conc.ToxConc += ToxConc

        results[key] = conc
    }

    //Printing results to final file
    for k, v := range results {
        new_record := []string{strconv.Itoa(k.X),
            strconv.Itoa(k.Y),
            strconv.FormatFloat(v.Conc, 'f', 10, 64),
            strconv.FormatFloat(v.ToxConc, 'f', 10, 64)}
        writer2.Write(new_record)
    }
    writer2.Flush()

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Structure

Functions..... you need more of them.

Your large, monolithic main method makes your code hard to follow, and separating out functions would help a lot.

Oh, and errors ... you need to handle them.

For a start, take this block:

```
    usage := `Chemical Sum.
Usage:
    chemical
    chemical <input_file>
    chemical <input_file> <output_file> [--chemical=<ch>] [--facility=<fc>] [--media=<md>] [--restore=<file>]
    chemical --help

Options:
    --chemical=<ch>      Query by chemical number
    --facility=<fc>      Query by facility number
    --media=<md>         Query by media
    --restore=<file>     Restore from file
    --help               Show this screen
    `
    arguments, _ := docopt.Parse(usage, nil, true, "Naval Fate 2.0", false)
```

And put it all in to a function:

```
func handleCommandLine() (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    ....
}
```

Now your main function is (with error handling ....):

```
func main() {
    arguments, err := handleCommandLine()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Right, options gone...

### Filtering

Let's look at the filtering now.... and, remember, in Go, functions are "first class" which means they can be a type, or variable.

```
type Filter func([]string) bool
```

Create a filter type, which is a function that takes a string slice input, and returns a bool. "Do we filter this string-slice?" Let's take our arguments, and create a system that returns a Filter for each type of supplied argument...

```
func BuildFilter(option string, field int, arguments map[string]interface{}) Filter {
    toadd := arguments[option]
    if len(toadd) == 0 {
        // nothing specified, no filtering.
        return nil
    }
    mapall := map[string]bool
    for _, val := range toadd {
        mapall[val] = true
    }

    // OK, now for the magic. Return a function!

    return func(row []string) bool {
        data := row[field]
        return mapall[data]
    }
}
```

OK, so we have a method, that takes your arguments, and returns a function that filters a CSV record if the right field is matching an argument.

Now, our main method can have:

```
// start with an empty slice of filters.
filters := []Filter{}
if filt := BuildFilter("--chemical", 4, arguments); filt != nil {
    filters = append(filters, filt)
}
if filt := BuildFilter("--facility", 5, arguments); filt != nil {
    filters = append(filters, filt)
}
if filt := BuildFilter("--media", 6, arguments); filt != nil {
    filters = append(filters, filt)
}
```

Even the bove can be simplified with a function to conditionally do the append...

```
func CheckFilter(filt Filter, filters []Filter) []Filter {
    if filt != nil {
        return append (filters, filt)
    }
    return filters
}
```

Now, your main method can be:

```
filters := []Filter{}
filters = CheckFilter(BuildFilter("--chemical", 4, arguments), filters)
filters = CheckFilter(BuildFilter("--facility", 5, arguments), filters)
filters = CheckFilter(BuildFilter("--media", 6, arguments), filters)
```

OK we have some filters (perhaps none, though - it may be empty). Let's make a function that simplifies some logic:

```
func KeepRecord(record []string, filters []Filter) bool {
    if len(filters) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    for _, filt := range filters {
        if filt(record) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Time for a change in direction...

### Double-Read

Why are you performing 2 read loops? One loop filters the data, and stores it in a temp file. The other loop reads the temp file, and aggregates the data.

You only need 1 loop (and then it really will be "streaming"...)

Let's simplify the loops. First up, discarding the header line... don't do that inside the loop, do it as a special case, outside the loop. Also, put your error handling after the statement that produces an error, don't put other logic in between.... this:

> ```
> rf, err := os.Open(input_file)
> r := csv.NewReader(rf)
>
> if err != nil {
>     log.Fatal("Error: %s", err)
> }
> ```

should be:

```
rf, err := os.Open(input_file)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Error: %s", err)
}

r := csv.NewReader(rf)
```

Now, discard the header....

```
if _, err := r.Read(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Unable to read the header: %v", err)
}
```

Then, have your loop, and, filter the records... But, let's get our aggregation system set up first, too....

```
results := make(map[Coordinates]SConc)
for {
    record, err := r.Read()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if !KeepRecord(record, filters) {
        continue
    }

    X, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[1])
    Y, _ := strconv.Atoi(record[2])
    Conc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(record[7], 32)
    ToxConc, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(record[8], 32)

    var key Coordinates
    key.X = X
    key.Y = Y

    conc := results[key]
    conc.Conc += Conc
    conc.ToxConc += ToxConc

    results[key] = conc
}
```

That's pretty much how it should look...

Comment: Wow! Great :) Will start with this, however results map does not fit memory - so I will return soon :)

Comment: Hmmm.. fails on `return func(row string[]) bool {` in go 1.4 and go 1.6. Error `syntax error: unexpected [, expecting comma or )`.

Comment: @NikolayFominyh - my java heritage is coming through, it should be `[]string` and not `string[]`. I have edited. Note that my review code is just typed in to the box, it has not been run. I am reviewing your code, not writing it ;-)